# passport-local with node-jwt-simple

Tags: node.js, authentication, token, jwt, passport.js

How can I combine passport-local to return a JWT token on successful authentication?

I want to use [node-jwt-simple](https://github.com/hokaccha/node-jwt-simple) and looking at [passport.js](http://passportjs.org/guide/username-password/) I am not sure how to go about.

```
var passport = require('passport')
  , LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
      if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

Is it possible to return the token when calling done() ?
Something like this... (just pseudo code)

```
if(User.validCredentials(username, password)) {
  var token = jwt.encode({username: username}, tokenSecret);
  done(null, {token : token}); //is this possible?
}
```

If not, how can I return the token?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

I figured it out!

First of all you need to implement the correct strategy. In my case LocalStrategy, and you need to provide your validation logic. For example sake let's use the one in passport-local.

```
var passport = require('passport')
  , LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
      if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

the verify call back you provide `function(username, password, done)` will take care of finding your user and checking if the password matches (beyond the scope of the question and my answer)

passport.js expects several pieces for it to work, one is that you return the user in the strategy. I was trying to change that part of the code, and that was wrong. The callback expects `false` if the validation fails and an `object` (the validated user) if you are successful.

Now.... how to integrate JWT?

In your login route you will have to handle a successful auth or an unsuccessful one. And it is here that you need to add the JWT token creation. Like so:

(remember to disable the session, otherwise you will have to implement the serialize and deserialize functions. And you don't need those if you are not persisting the session, which you are not if you are using a token based auth)

From passport-local examples: (with the JWT token added)

```
// POST /login
//   This is an alternative implementation that uses a custom callback to
//   achieve the same functionality.
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err) }
    if (!user) {
      return res.json(401, { error: 'message' });
    }

    //user has authenticated correctly thus we create a JWT token 
    var token = jwt.encode({ username: 'somedata'}, tokenSecret);
    res.json({ token : token });

  })(req, res, next);
});
```

And that is it! Now when you call /login and POST username and password (which should always be over SSL) the first code snippet above will try to find a user based on the username you provided and then check that the password matches (Of course you will need to change that to suit your needs).

After that your login route will be called and there you can take care of returning an error or a valid token.

Hope this will help someone. And if I have made any mistakes or forgot something let me know.

Comment: Passport's [BasicStrategy](http://passportjs.org/guide/basic-digest/) or DigestStrategy are two other options. There doesn't seem to be a huge difference between Basic and Local strategies, though, since neither need sessions to work - just that Local asks for redirect URLs (making it slightly less API friendly).

Comment: Hey @cgiacomi could you give an example of a route that checks the token?

Comment: Hey @matt-kim actually I don't save the token, it's transient. I don't know if it the best way or not but this is what I do: 

The user authenticates, and I generate the token and return it to the client. The token is stored in localStorage if the client is a website, or you could store it in an iPhone/Android app.

When a client has to make a request for a resource it sends the saved token to the backend. Passport will handle the token. Here is a gist with the Bearer strategy to handle the token

https://gist.github.com/cgiacomi/cd1efa187b8cccbe2a61

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Hey @cgiacomi! maybe it is obvious, but could you describe how you disable the sessions when using the custom callback?

Comment: Have you tried using a twitter strategy? I haven't figure it out how to implement passport-twitter with jwt.

Comment: @Jobsamuel No I am sorry, I haven't tried any other strategy. The reason being that I wanted my clients to authenticate using email and password, which would result in a token that could be used in subsequent API calls to my REST backend. This would allow me to use for example, Angular from a browser and native iPhone and Android apps. Yet the authentication mechanism would be the same no matter what the client is.

Comment: @MrMuh checkout the link https://gist.github.com/cgiacomi/cd1efa187b8cccbe2a61 in my comment I show how to disable sessions: passport.authenticate('bearer', { session: false })

Comment: There is now a passport jwt strategy at https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-jwt

Answer (score 20):

This is a great solution, I just want to add this:

```
var expressJwt = require('express-jwt');

app.use('/api', expressJwt({secret: secret}));
```

I like to use **"express-jwt"** to validate the token.

btw: this article is great to learn how to handle the token in the client side, using Angular, in order to send it back with every request

https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/

Comment: I've only used `express-jwt` to do authentication, but reading through documentation of other packages such as `passport-jwt`, I think I'll be sticking to `express-jwt`. Much simpler, much nicer IMO

Comment: Just an FYI express-jwt does not provide support for refresh tokens.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a boiler-plate I'm working on for specifically using api tokens only (no sessions...not that session are bad of course; just we're using token approach):
https://github.com/roblevintennis/passport-api-tokens