# Passport Session management when cookies are disabled

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sails.js, passport.js, passport-local

I am making a web app with AgularJS as my front-end and Sails(NodeJS + Express) as my backend.
I am using passport (passport-local) for authentication and it all seemed to work great until I tested it in safari. I noticed that the sessions would always return null.

I was using passport session for authorization and I couldn't fetch the session variable using req.session.passport since it was empty. I figured out that I had cookies disabled in Safari. 
This would break my app's authorization. Is there a way to have session management which would work even if cookies are disabled in a browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to cookies is tokens.

One popular implementation of tokens is [JSON Web Tokens (JWT)](http://jwt.io/). There is a module for using them with Express called [express-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt) and a [blog post](https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/) showing how to use it. For integration with Passport, you may use [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20274700/2050455) as a guide.