# JWT in Sails.js with passport

Tags: node.js, sails.js, passport.js, jwt

Does someone know how to use JWT in sails.js with passport?

I saw this link to do it node.js : [passport-local with node-jwt-simple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20228572/passport-local-with-node-jwt-simple)

But routes and controllers with sails-generate-auth seems differents so I don't know how to integrate it

Comment: I went through this nice tutorial here: https://ericswann.wordpress.com/2015/04/24/nozus-js-1-intro-to-sails-with-passport-and-jwt-json-web-token-auth/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a repo on github doing exactly what I was looking for(passport + jsonwebtokens with sails on the back) with in bonus a frontend written in angular

https://github.com/ProLoser/angular-sails-seed

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [waterlock.ninja](http://waterlock.ninja) it's made for sailsJS and does all the JWT stuff OOTB :)

Comment: I already saw waterlock...In node.js I used passport but I'm new in sails... The fact is that I would continue to use passport with sails( I took the package sails-generate-auth).

Comment: it is simple to swap over to waterlock and it will make your life a ton easier!

Comment: @AmanGautam To be fair that is not true - as I commented here: https://github.com/waterlock/waterlock/issues/118#issuecomment-208983502 I am working on v2 here https://github.com/wayne-o/waterlock here https://github.com/wayne-o/waterlock-google-auth here https://github.com/wayne-o/waterlock-facebook-auth here https://github.com/wayne-o/waterlock-local-auth and a new Spotify auth here https://github.com/wayne-o/waterlock-spotify-auth - This is OS software - meaning you can chime in at any point.

Comment: Hey - i have commit access to the main repos .I'm just getting my stuff stable enough before i start pushing it back up - there are a few breaking changes and I've taken the liberty to make some decisions that will need to be discussed with the other team members and users of the project  -what suits me might not suit everybody :)